# Is it possible to only trigger a Pipeline if certain files are changed?

Tags: git, automation, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project with a working GitLab-CI configuration, but I only want to create and execute a pipeline, when one of my config files are changed. Is there a way to check for changed files within the gitlab-ci.yml and only execute, when specified files are changed?

Comment: Probably not, but why not flip it around - check in the pipeline whether the files you care about changed, and only run your other (test, build, etc.) scripts if they have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using `changes`: add or exclude jobs from a pipeline based on what files are changed. Same as `only:changes`.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges

Warning: If using only:changes with only allow merge requests to be merged if the pipeline succeeds, undesired behavior could result if you don’t also use only:merge_requests.

Also, it's always evaluates as “true” in Scheduled pipelines. All files are considered to have “changed” when a scheduled pipeline runs.